# How to update/add/delete rows in table with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new to Javascript. I'm trying to implement Ajax system in my coursework in order to update the html table without updating the whole page. My HTML table is basically the table from my database, so Ajax should update the MySQl table, but how can I refresh the actual table on webpage? Another question is can I use different .php files for each action and just call them with ajax? How can I display the forms in the message box for adding the row or should I just redirect to a new page where the will be the forms for a new row? 
Here is my table:

```
<?php
include("audentificate.php");
include ('db.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM Trains";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Departures table for workers </title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="table" align="center">
    <div style = "background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:20px;"><b>Departures Table for workers</b></div>
    <table border="1" align="center" width="700">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Change row</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Train Company</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input id = 'tick' type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Traincompany'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Destination']  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Time'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Platform']  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Date'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="message">Logout from user<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to display the contents of your MySQL tables? Or are you actually trying to change the data as well? Because if you just want to display information, you're not going to need a form at all.

Comment: I already have a code that displays a table from MySQL. I want to write add/delete/change system using AJAX to update the table without opening other pages.